# What is the expected value of the die tossing game when it terminates?

Tags: probability, expected-value

Suppose that you have a fair die. You gain $+1$ when you toss an even number and lose $-1$ otherwise. The game ends when you have a net positive gain (i.e., net positive gain is $+1$).

What is the expected value of your gain when the game terminates. This is just a symmetric random walk problem, but I am confused. The game terminates when our net positive gain is $1$. So isn't it deterministic that when the game terminates, our expected value is simply $1$?

I am not confident in this result because I believe it would require absolute certainty, and not simply "almost surely" that the game will terminate (i.e., we reach a net positive gain). Without the absolute certainty, there is some chance that our game will continue indefinitely. So this question actually seems ill-posed to me because it seems to assume that the game terminates.

Comment: The prob. tossing an odd number after n-tosses is $\left(\frac12\right)^n$. Then $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty } \left(\frac12\right)^n=0$ This is sure, not almost sure only.

Comment: I think you may be asking the wrong question.  I suspect you are asked is the expected number of tosses.

Comment: I believe the question is asking about the total gain vs. the net gain. For example, if you toss odd (i.e., lose $-1$), then toss even (i.e., gain $+1$) and toss even again (i.e., gain $+1$), the game ends. Your net gain is just $1$, but your total gain is $1 + 1 = 2$. As herb steinberg mentions above, this is of course related to the expected number of tosses (i.e., if $e$ is the expected number of tosses, the question is asking for $\frac{e +1}{2}$).

Comment: @herbsteinberg No, I was asked the expected profit at when the game ends. Though now you mention I am curious about the expected number of tosses as well. Would it be finite?

Comment: @JohnOmielan No, the question is asking about the net gain. Specifically, the question is phrased as "What is the expected net profit when the game ends." But I replied to Herb above, I'm curious about the total gain as well. Is this expectation finite?